# Python - inheritance and method overriding

Tags: python, class, inheritance, overriding

I have two classes, one inheriting from the other. Let's call them `Parent` and `Child`. 
Both of the objects created from those classes should use function `funA`, which looks like below

```
funA():
  X = another_function()
  Y = # some value
  X.append(Y)
  # do other computations
```

For both classes, function `funA` looks almost the same, except function `another_function()`, which computes in a different way the list `X` for the `Parent` and differently for the `Child`. Of course, I know that I can override function `funA` in the Child class, but since this function is very long and does several operations, copy-pasting it would be a little bit a waste. On the other hand - I have to distinguish that the Parent class should use one version of `another_function()` and the Child class should use the second version of `another_function()`. Is is maybe possible to point which version of `another_function` (let's call them `another_function_v1` and `another_function_v2`) should be used by each class or the only solution if to override the whole function `funA`?

Comment: Why not replace the call to `another_function` with a call to `function_calling_method`, then just override *that* in the child?

Comment: is your `funA` static or class/instance method?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov it is an class method

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can you explain more precisely what you mean?

Comment: then what's the problem to do `X = cls.another_function()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post is not quite clear but I assume `funA` is a method of `Parent`. If yes, just add some `another_method` method calling the right function:

```
class Parent(object):
    def another_method(self):
        return another_function_v1()

    def funA(self):
        X = self.another_method()
        Y = # some value
        X.append(Y)
        # do other computations

class Child(Parent):
    def another_method(self):
        return another_method_v2()
```

nb if `funA` is a classmethod you will want to make `another_method` a classmethod too...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where your another_functions come. I suppose they are normal functions, which can be imported and used

```
class Parent(object):
    another_function = another_function_v1
    def funA(self):
        X = self.another_function()
        Y = # some value
        X.append(Y)
        # do other computations

class Child(Parent):
    another_function = another_function_v2
```